# PHP multi-dimentional array condensing

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am using an array like this for a static file cache:

```
[
  key => data => [
             key1 => data    => [...]
                  => expires => 123456
             key2 => data    => [...]
                  => expires => 123456
         ]
      => expires => 123456
]
```

This can be many levels deep (sometimes 10-15 levels).

What I would like to do is return only the values of data, so for instance, to create an array like so

```
[
    key => key1 => [...]
        => key2 => [...]
]
```

how would I do this?

EDIT

`print_r` of the structure

```
Array ( 
[key] => 
    Array (
    [data] => 
        Array (
        [key1] => 
            Array (
            [data] => Array ( ... )
            [expires] => 12345678)
        [key2] =>
            Array (
                [data] => Array ( ... )
                [expires] => 12345678
            )
        ) 
    [expires] => 12345678
    )
)
```

Comment: That notation does not look like php...

Comment: Could you please make that array structure more clear by editing your question above: do I _guess_ right that every array contains an element called data and you want to get rid of that?

Comment: yeah key1 => data => [...] is pretty confusing. is [...] another array? because as I see you have some arrays with no keys at all

Comment: the notation is a representation of the array values and structure. and yes, [...] is a repeat of the same array structure as before.

Comment: What would be the last value of the keys? Because your converter function could be depend on this.

Comment: it could be either an array of values or a string

Comment: Did you try the [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function?

Comment: You can't use it as : "Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function." from php.net

Comment: Will there any key sits beside data (`array([data]=>...,[expire]=12345,[key]=>array())`), or only key by key, data by expire (`array([key]=>array([data]=>...,[expire]=12345))`)?

Comment: They will not need to sit beside data, they'll always be a data/expire  key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursive function like this:

```
function extractValues($array, &$result){

    foreach($array as $key1 => $val1){
        if($key1 == 'data' && is_array($val1)) {
            foreach($val1 as $key2 => $val2){

                if(is_array($val2)) {
                    $result[$key2] = array();
                    extractValues($val2, $result[$key2]);
                } else {
                    $result[$key2] = $val2;
                }
            }
        } else if(!in_array($key1, array('expires'))) {
            $result[$key1] = array();
            extractValues($val1, $result[$key1]);
        }

    }

    return $result;
}
```

It will work on array structure like this:

```
$test = array(
    'key' => array(
        'data' => array(
            'key1' => array(
                'data' => array(
                    'key11' => 11,
                    'key12' => 12,
                ),
            ),
            'key2' => array(
                'data' => array(
                    'key21' => 21,
                    'key22' => 22,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'expires' => 12345,
    ),
);

$result = array();
extractValues($test, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

This is the result of the var_dump() hope meets your requirement:

```
array(1) {
  ["key"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key1"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["key11"]=>
      int(11)
      ["key12"]=>
      int(12)
    }
    ["key2"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["key21"]=>
      int(21)
      ["key22"]=>
      int(22)
    }
  }
}
```